# No WIFI in BLFS 8.4

Tags: wifi, wpa-supplicant, lfs

I have built the BLFS 8.4 but WIFI doesn't work on it. The boot gives an error message

```
Starting wpa_supplicant on the wlan0 interface...Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
Could not read interface wlan0 flags: No such device
WEXT: Could not set  interface 'wlan0' UP
wlan0: Failed to initialize driver interface
*****

*****face wlan0 doesn't exist.
```

I did the configuration again with wlp2s0 because that is my interface. Now the boot does not give the error but still cannot access internet through wifi.

The output of `ip link` is

```
bash-5.0# ip link
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 70:5a:b6:8f:2b:56 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: sit0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1480 qdisc noop state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/sit 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
4: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d6:c3:d9:15:c1:dc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

Below is the output of `iwconfig`

```
bash-5.0# iwconfig
sit0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"iBall-Baton"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.437 GHz  Access Point: 00:1E:A6:DF:94:F4   
          Bit Rate=1 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=50/70  Signal level=-60 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:1  Invalid misc:6   Missed beacon:0
```

Below is the output for `ifup wlp2s0`

```
  *  Bringing up the wlp2s0 interface...                                       [  OK  ]
     
  *  ting wpa_supplicant on the wlp2s0 interface...                            [  OK  ]

  *  Adding IPv4 address 192.168.1.216 to the wlp2s0 interface...              [  OK  ]
     
  S  Gateway already setup; skipping.                                          [ SKIP ]
```

Output of `/etc/sysconfig/ifconfig.wlp2s0`

```
ONBOOT="yes"
IFACE="wlp2s0"
SERVICE="wpa"
# Additional arguments to wpa_supplicant
WPA_ARGS=""

WPA_SERVICE="ipv4-static"
IP="192.168.1.216"
GATEWAY="192.168.1.1"
PREFIX="24"
BROADCAST="192.168.1.255"
```

Output of `/etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant-wlp2s0.conf`

```
network={
        ssid="iBall-Baton"
        #psk="hamburger"
        psk=98562f1a2fa154c127a1ebe9daeecce837edcc57365b6b9b05ffcf2c50bbea0c
}
```

Output of `/etc/resolv.conf`

```
cat /etc/resolv.conf
domain ib-wrb304n.setup.in
search ib-wrb304n.setup.in
nameserver 192.168.1.1
```

Output of `ping 8.8.8.8`

```
ping 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8): 56 data bytes
92 bytes from 192.168.1.213: Destination Host Unreachable
92 bytes from 192.168.1.213: Destination Host Unreachable
92 bytes from 192.168.1.213: Destination Host Unreachable
^C92 bytes from 192.168.1.213: Destination Host Unreachable
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 0 packets received, 100% packet loss
```

Comment: I added the output of the config files.

Comment: "cannot access internet through wifi" can mean different things... You've configured the interface to use a static address. My guess is you're missing DNS configuration. What does `/etc/resolv.conf` look like? What does `ping google.com` output? and `ping 8.8.8.8`?

Comment: @rfmodulator The command iwconfig shows that I have an interface of wlp2s0 but the boot is displaying an error for a missing file of `/etc/sysconfig/wpa_supplicant-wifi0.conf`. I also tried to change my **wlp2s0 ip _.216_** to **enp3s0 ip _.213_** but it didn't work.

Comment: Maybe it's as simple as renaming the .conf file?

Comment: When I first compiled it, it was same as wifi0.conf